# PDFJS viewer showing wrong colors of PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, odoo, pdf.js

When showing some PDF files (other cases are fine) on the PDFJS viewer, it shows with worng color combination, with like a red and yellow filter over it.

PDFJS viewer wrong display:

[image: PDFJS viewer]

Downloading the same file from the viewer and displaying it locally:

[image: Local display of the same PDF]

I just tried to display a PDF using PDFJS library with it's original colors, and the colors got changed.

Comment: I suspect the whole page is an image, and it's simply PdfJS getting the display of the image wrong. Can you supply the PDF?

Comment: The PDF is an Adobe Illustrator rendered project, sure this is it.

Comment: it.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CsAsHiSXODPJXSyO11Be3wqw9fDUOj0v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was wrong: it's not all an image. However, the whole page appears to be covered also with a shading. My guess is PdfJS gets the shading wrong. Report to PdfJS as a bug.